# Python GCP Function BORB PDF - TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, borb

I have been trying to generate an invoice pdf in a gcp function that receives the following input:

```
end_client_invoices15jjltjkq38p {'oldValue': {}, 'updateMask': {}, 'value': {'createTime': '2023-04-10T13:05:38.934111Z', 'fields': {'buyerDetails': {'mapValue': {'fields': {'buyer_address_city_postal_code_country': {'stringValue': 'Town A AB500 Country'}, 'buyer_address_street': {'stringValue': 'Street 12 '}, 'buyer_email': {'stringValue': 'user@gmail.com'}, 'buyer_id': {'stringValue': 'tqNPjTbvbQQxAUwjp6uVqnrybLh1'}, 'buyer_name': {'stringValue': 'William Surname'}, 'buyer_phone': {'stringValue': '+34 666 111 222'}}}}, 'invoice_number': {'integerValue': '4'}, 'product': {'mapValue': {'fields': {'VAT': {'doubleValue': 0.16}, 'amount': {'doubleValue': 2.0}, 'description': {'stringValue': 'description'}, 'price_per_unit_without_VAT': {'doubleValue': 3.5}, 'quantity': {'doubleValue': 1.0}}}}, 'sellerDetails': {'mapValue': {'fields': {'seller_address_city_postal_code_country': {'stringValue': 'Town AD123 Andorra'}, 'seller_address_street': {'stringValue': '30 Street'}, 'seller_email': {'stringValue': 'user@gmail.com'}, 'seller_name': {'stringValue': 'Name'}, 'seller_phone': {'stringValue': '+376 125 142'}, 'store_uid': {'stringValue': 'Kz7gUu2kokgKdmwTXcSB'}}}}}, 'name': 'projects/project-prod/databases/(default)/documents/invoices_end_client/3CCievchkZHsIVDGQ5oR', 'updateTime': '2023-04-10T13:05:38.934111Z'}}
```

```
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.page_layout.multi_column_layout import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.page_layout.page_layout import PageLayout
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from borb.pdf.document.document import Document
from borb.pdf.page.page import Page
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.page_layout.multi_column_layout import SingleColumnLayout
from decimal import Decimal
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.table.fixed_column_width_table import (
    FixedColumnWidthTable as Table,
)
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.layout_element import Alignment
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.image.image import Image
from borb.pdf.page.page_size import PageSize
from datetime import datetime
import random
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF
from borb.pdf.canvas.color.color import HexColor, X11Color
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.table.fixed_column_width_table import (
    FixedColumnWidthTable as Table,
)
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.table.table import TableCell
from borb.pdf import Page
import json
from google.cloud import storage
from datetime import datetime
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
from pprint import pformat
import logging
import re
import pandas as pd

# Global Variables
export_time = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
invoice_date_month = datetime.now().strftime("%m_%Y")

logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')

# Function
def generate_pdf_invoice(data, context):
    """ Triggered by a change to a Firestore document.
    Args:
        data (dict): The event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """

    logging.warning(list(data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["amount"].values())[0])
    logging.warning(data)
    # Build Table
    table_001 = Table(number_of_rows=4, number_of_columns=4)

    table_001.add(
        Paragraph(
            "Raó Social", font="Helvetica-Bold", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.LEFT
        )
    )
    table_001.add(
        Paragraph(
            "Company, SL", font="Helvetica-Bold"
        )
    )

    table_001.add(
        Paragraph("Data", font="Helvetica-Bold", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT)
    )
    now = datetime.now()
    table_001.add(Paragraph("%d/%d/%d" % (now.day, now.month, now.year)))

    table_001.add(
        Paragraph("Carrer", font="Helvetica-Bold", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.LEFT)
    )
    table_001.add(
        Paragraph("Street A,Bloc X")
    )
    table_001.add(
        Paragraph(
            "Factura #", font="Helvetica-Bold", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT,
        )
    )
    table_001.add(
        Paragraph(str(data["value"]["fields"]["invoice_number"]["integerValue"]))
    )

    table_001.add(
        Paragraph(
            "Població", font="Helvetica-Bold", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.LEFT
        )
    )

    table_001.add(
        Paragraph("Town")
    )

    table_001.add(
        Paragraph(
            "Venciment", font="Helvetica-Bold", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.LEFT
        )
    )
    table_001.add(Paragraph("%d/%d/%d" % (now.day, now.month, now.year)))

    table_001.add(
        Paragraph("Email", font="Helvetica-Bold", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT)
    )
    table_001.add(
        Paragraph(
            "company@gmail.com"
        )
    )

    table_001.set_padding_on_all_cells(Decimal(2), Decimal(2), Decimal(2), Decimal(2))
    table_001.no_borders()

    #Billing and shipping information
    table_002 = Table(number_of_columns=1, number_of_rows=6)
    table_002.add(
        Paragraph(
            "Facturat a",
            background_color=HexColor("263238"),
            font_color=X11Color("White"),
        )
    )
    # BILLING
    table_002.add(
        Paragraph(remove_emoji(data["value"]["fields"]["buyerDetails"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["buyer_name"]["stringValue"]))
    )  # BILLING
    table_002.add(
        Paragraph(data["value"]["fields"]["buyerDetails"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["buyer_address_street"]["stringValue"])
    )  # BILLING
    table_002.add(
        Paragraph(
            data["value"]["fields"]["buyerDetails"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["buyer_address_city_postal_code_country"]["stringValue"]
        )
    )  # BILLING
    table_002.add(
        Paragraph(data["value"]["fields"]["buyerDetails"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["buyer_phone"]["stringValue"])
    )  # BILLING
    table_002.add(
        Paragraph(data["value"]["fields"]["buyerDetails"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["buyer_email"]["stringValue"])
    )  # BILLING
    table_002.set_padding_on_all_cells(Decimal(2), Decimal(2), Decimal(2), Decimal(2))
    table_002.no_borders()

    # Build_itemized_description_table
    table_003 = Table(number_of_rows=7, number_of_columns=4)
    for h in ["Descripció", "Quantitat", "Preu per unitat", "Import"]:
        table_003.add(
            TableCell(
                Paragraph(h, font_color=X11Color("White")),
                background_color=HexColor("000000"),
            )
        )

    odd_color = HexColor("BBBBBB")
    even_color = HexColor("FFFFFF")
    for row_number, item in enumerate(
        [
            (
                data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["description"]["stringValue"],
                data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["quantity"]["doubleValue"],
                list(data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["price_per_unit_without_VAT"].values())[0],
                list(data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["price_per_unit_without_VAT"].values())[0]*data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["quantity"]["doubleValue"]
            ),
        ]
    ):
        c = even_color if row_number % 2 == 0 else odd_color
        table_003.add(TableCell(Paragraph(item[0]), background_color=c))
        table_003.add(TableCell(Paragraph(str(item[1])), background_color=c))
        table_003.add(TableCell(Paragraph("$ " + str(item[2])), background_color=c))
        table_003.add(TableCell(Paragraph("$ " + str(item[3])), background_color=c))

    # Optionally add some empty rows to have a fixed number of rows for styling purposes
    for row_number in range(3, 5):
        c = even_color if row_number % 2 == 0 else odd_color
        for _ in range(0, 4):
            table_003.add(TableCell(Paragraph(" "), background_color=c))

    table_003.add(
        TableCell(
            Paragraph(
                "Subtotal", font="Helvetica-Bold", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT,
            ),
            col_span=3,
        )
    )
    table_003.add(
        TableCell(
            Paragraph(
                float(data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["price_per_unit_without_VAT"]["doubleValue"])*float(data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["quantity"]["doubleValue"])
            )
        )
    )
    table_003.add(
        TableCell(
            Paragraph(
                "IGI", font="Helvetica-Bold", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT
            ),
            col_span=3,
        )
    )
    table_003.add(
        TableCell(
            Paragraph(
                "{0:.2f}".format(
                    float(data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["price_per_unit_without_VAT"]["doubleValue"]) * float(data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["quantity"]["doubleValue"]) * 4.5 / 100
                )
            )
        )
    )
    table_003.add(
        TableCell(
            Paragraph(
                "Total", font="Helvetica-Bold", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT
            ),
            col_span=3,
        )
    )
    table_003.add(
        TableCell(
            Paragraph(
                "{0:.2f}".format(
                    float(data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["price_per_unit_without_VAT"]["doubleValue"])*float(data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["quantity"]["doubleValue"]) * (1 + 4.5 / 100)
                )            
            )
        )
    )
    table_003.set_padding_on_all_cells(Decimal(2), Decimal(2), Decimal(2), Decimal(2))
    table_003.no_borders()


    # Create document
    pdf = Document()
    # Add page
    page = Page()

    pdf.add_page(page)

    page_layout = SingleColumnLayout(page)
    page_layout.vertical_margin = page.get_page_info().get_height() * Decimal(0.02)

    page_layout.add(
        Image(
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mes-k-bo-dev.appspot.com/o/stores%2F2322e310-1743-11ed-87c2-9f7ebec4c7dc?alt=media&token=71ebb1be-a9ae-4f49-b3e1-b46619cdfb4a",
            width=Decimal(128),
            height=Decimal(128),
        )
    )


    # Invoice information table
    page_layout.add(table_001)
    # Empty paragraph for spacing
    page_layout.add(Paragraph(" "))
    # Billing and shipping information table
    page_layout.add(table_002)
    # Empty paragraph for spacing
    page_layout.add(Paragraph(" "))
    # Itemized description
    page_layout.add(table_003)
```

And I am getting this error which I can't figure out how to solve:

```
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 260, in generate_pdf_invoice 
    page_layout.add(table_003)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/page_layout/multi_column_layout.py", line 201, in add
    layout_rect = layout_element.layout(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/layout_element.py", line 307, in layout 
    return self.calculate_layout_box_and_do_layout(page, bounding_box)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/layout_element.py", line 320, in calculate_layout_box_and_do_layout
    layout_box = self._calculate_layout_box(page, bounding_box)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/layout_element.py", line 230, in _calculate_layout_box
    returned_layout_box = self._calculate_layout_box_without_padding(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/layout_element.py", line 258, in _calculate_layout_box_without_padding
    layout_rect = self._do_layout_without_padding(page, bounding_box)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/table/fixed_column_width_table.py", line 131, in _do_layout_without_padding
    t.layout(page, Rectangle(x, y, w, h))
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/table/table.py", line 151, in layout
    returned_layout_box: Rectangle = self._layout_element.layout(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/layout_element.py", line 307, in layout
    return self.calculate_layout_box_and_do_layout(page, bounding_box)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/layout_element.py", line 320, in calculate_layout_box_and_do_layout
    layout_box = self._calculate_layout_box(page, bounding_box)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/layout_element.py", line 230, in _calculate_layout_box
    returned_layout_box = self._calculate_layout_box_without_padding(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/layout_element.py", line 258, in _calculate_layout_box_without_padding
    layout_rect = self._do_layout_without_padding(page, bounding_box)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/borb/pdf/canvas/layout/text/paragraph.py", line 230, in _do_layout_without_padding
    if len(self._text) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Could anyone help me?
Thousand thanks!

Several variations of the code but could not get it to work, mainly trying more configuration of the paragraph without success

Comment: I would guess that one of the `Paragraph` objects you are creating has been given a `float` value rather than a string. Go through them all and check that all of them are created with strings.

Comment: So just to be sure, has that fixed the problem and your code can now generate PDFs?

Answer (score 1):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`

One of your `Paragraph` objects is being constructed with a `float` rather than a `str`. At some point, the `Paragraph` attempts to perform layout, for which it needs to determine its width.

And thus it calls `len` on what it expects to be `str`, but is in fact `float`.

This is where it goes wrong:

```py
    table_003.add(
        TableCell(
            Paragraph(
                float(data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["price_per_unit_without_VAT"]["doubleValue"])*float(data["value"]["fields"]["product"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["quantity"]["doubleValue"])
            )
        )
    )
```

You are explicitly constructing `Paragraph` with a `float` there.